# Can tortoiseSVN add to the file matadata the revision nunber of the file?

Tags: metadata, tortoisesvn

This is probably a dum question but!!
I was wandering if TortoiseSVN can add to the file matadata the revision number of the file. Because I use TortoiseSVN to save and keep track of excel files and the changes made in them but it its a pain when I'm trying to know with witch version of the file was used!

thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Excel files are binary files. You first need to investigate whether you know how to add that information manually (i.e with a script, not by opening Excel and typing) and they maybe you can automate it with a hook.

Comment: I can manualy add information to the "details" in the properties of the file! I was wandering if TortoiseSVN could add information in there!

Comment: That's pretty much like typing the information in Excel itself. Windows explorer parses the file and offers a visual interface to edit it.

Comment: I believe that LibreOffice Calc can run in command-line, it might be an option to explore.